# C# calculate data table column for chart

Tags: c#, datatable

I would like to add a column to my data table by calculating the items from other columns. I know, that I can do it that way:

```
workTable.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(Double));  
workTable.Columns.Add("Distance", typeof(Double));  
workTable.Columns.Add("Velocity", typeof(Double), "Distance / Time");
```

In my case I need to add actually Velocity which is defined as:
(Distance-previous Distance) / (Time-previous Time).

So I would like to know how to make a new column by using values from other rows of the data table.

Comment: How you populate workTable?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the code. It did not worked as expected for me.

1. The loop must start with 1, not 0.
2. And then I don't understand how velocity was calculated, the result was just as I multiply Distance with a constant number.
   I changed the code to the one below, which works now.

   ```
   for (int i = 1; i < workTable.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       DataRow row = workTable.Rows[i];
       double velocity = (workTable.Rows[i].Field<double>("Distance") - 
       workTable.Rows[i-1].Field<double>("Distance")) / 
       (workTable.Rows[i].Field<double> 
       ("Time") - table.Rows[i - 1].Field<double>("Time"));
       row.SetField("Velocity", velocity);
   }
   ```